# HTML DOM: why do some of the events don't bubble up during event delegation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, event-bubbling

While trying to understand the concept of Event Delegation, I came across a few events like focus, blur, load, unload, change, reset, scroll which didn't bubble up to the parent, however events like click, keyup worked just fine. What is the reason behind some of the events not bubbling up?

Comment: It's the nature or origin of the event. Like `window` events can't bubble because it doesn't have any ancestors. `focus` very purpose is to well *focus* on a single element at a time.

Comment: [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) bubbles. It's notable, that in jQuery event model, all events are bubbling.